# Algorithm to determine if a graph is symmetric

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I found [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SymmetricGraph.html) the definition of symmetric graphs.

It is said in the corresponding pages for [edge-transitive graphs](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Edge-TransitiveGraph.html) and [vertex-transitive graphs](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vertex-TransitiveGraph.html) that a future version of Wolfram language will have two functions to determine if a graph has those properties.

I think I understand intuitively the definition of edge-transitive and vertex-transitive as the possibility to exchange any two edges or vertices respectively and obtain the same graph, and I am able to find those graphs by hand for the smallest cases.

My question is: how can an algorithm with a reasonable time complexity be written to verify if a graph is edge-transitive and vertex-transitive? And is it possible to do it without recurring to the automorphism group concept?

Basically, I am curious to understand how they can have computed the highest index term in [OEIS A286931](https://oeis.org/A286931). The sequence is interesting because the values seem lower with a prime number of vertices.

So also an algorithm to count the symmetric graphs with a given number of vertices would be nice to know.

Comment: I imagine that to compute the sequence, you'd want to count the graphs with a given automorphism group as a subroutine. This is much easier than finding the automorphism group, starting from a graph.

Comment: Yes, mainly I would like to just count the graphs.